# VS 2013 - Elide Generic parameters in compilation errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've recently come across a problem in some C# code where using outer parameters with many generic arguments is the most natural solution. (In effect, the problem is that our code base has two almost identical modules with a distressing amount of code repetition. These modules consist of classes that are structurally virtually identical, but are related in such a way that normal OO abstraction (interfaces / base classes) does not suffice to express their commonality.) So a typical file in the common code might look like:

```
public partial class Module<T1, T2, ..., TN>
{
    public abstract class Foo
    {
        public virtual T1 DoFoo(T2 t2, T3, t3)
        {
            //... 
        }
    }
}
```

where `N` is a very large number.

This all works fairly cleanly when the code is correct, but when a compilation error is triggered Visual Studio includes the generic parameters in the error messages leading to illegible messages like, say:

```
Error in Module<T1, T2, ..., TN>.Foo.DoFoo
     missing ';' on 13:83
```

The `Module<...>` business takes up so much space that it's very hard to even see what  the error is.

Ideally, I would like to be able to configure VS 2013/process the error messages such that generic parameters are not included and we get instead something like

```
Error in Module<>.Foo.DoFoo missing ';'
```

Comment: Generally lots of parameters is a code smell (whether its method parameters, or type parameters). You *appear* to be trying to hide the problem, rather than fix the solution. Whilst DRY is a worthy aim, it shouldn't be pursued at the expense of readability.

Comment: David, I understand the concern. In this case we have to be worried about the trade-offs between understandable and maintainable code. Having two largish (~12k) modules that must exhibit the exact same functionality which are independent of one another is a maintenance nightmare. I think the maintenance worries are severe enough to justify an alternative which may be less readable.